# entity framework get parent including

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Can this code be done more efficient?

a template should include its children units.

To use the include I have to return templates not a singleOrDefault template...

This works technically and compiles:

```
public Template StartTemplate(int templateId)
        {
            var templates = _context.Templates.Where(t => t.TemplateId == templateId).Include(i => i.Units)
            return templates.Single();
        }
```

This works not as the .Include() is only available on IEnumerable

```
    public Template StartTemplate(int templateId)
            {
                var template = _context.Templates.Single(t => t.TemplateId == templateId).Include(i => i.Units)
return template;                 
            }
```

How can I improve the working code?

Comment: This is extremely vague and the example doesn't make sense.  Why `ToList()` if you are then just going to return `Single()`, just use `Single()`.

Comment: The first option works. What's wrong with it? It returns 1 template with units.

Comment: But it is an IEnumerable<Template> is it not possible to return a single template with its children without doing at the end the template.Single();?

Comment: No. What's the trouble with `Single()` if you want a single item?